# Running windows on iMac updates system settings

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, bootcamp, software

When I boot my iMac onto windows partition and then reboot into Snow Leopard my system time is updated (reverted on hour back). 
This occurs even though I have 'locked' the system time on Snow Leopard.

I'm not sure if related but my connection to wi-fi is also affected. By this I mean I lose my internet connection and to re-connect to my internet wi-fi.

Comment: You really need to elaborate about “a little work” if you want an answer about this part  ;)

Comment: Will do, question edited. I use my iMac for personal use so will be probably a day before I try your solution. thanks!

Comment: You should split your question in two, since you're not sure it is related. The format here is Q&A, not so much "forum" where all of your problems are trying to be diagnosed: the goal is to give a definitive answer to one precise question. I'd advise changing the title of the question to something more precise than “system settings” and talk about the system time, then creating another question regarding your Wi-Fi problem  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Time issue

It is a [known issue](http://www.google.com/search?q=boot%20camp%20time%20issue&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) that is due to the fact that OS X and Windows both store the time in the hardware, but OS X does in GMT while Windows stores local time.

There are at least two distinct ways to fix it:

1. Set Windows time zone to GMT and remove the daylight savings time offset and also turn off network time sync. ([Source](http://paulstamatiou.com/boot-camp-bug#comment-117548975))
2. Use a [startup batch script](http://grupenet.com/2007/12/04/fix-boot-camp-time-offset/).